# Way to send data from router to frontend js

Tags: javascript, node.js, send

On node.js server I have router for get requests:

> router.js:

```
   router.get("/car/index", auth, async (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.user); // prints a name of a logged user
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../../public/car.html"));
    });
```

In the time when get request is made, I have in req.user parameter saved a name of user who is logged in. I'd need to send this name to my frontend javascript. That means, to frontend javascript file carController.js which is connectent with car.html webpage:

> car.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    ..........
    <script
      type="module"
      defer
      src="/js/controllers/carController.js"
    ></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Any way to make it?

Comment: Web Socket... Look from ws implementation

Comment: https://github.com/websockets/ws

Answer (score 0):

Have you think in using ejs? (https://ejs.co/)

You can render a html page and embed javascript data.
In the webpage you have some examples.